# Inputs going into lists and adding

Tags: python, list, input, addition

This may be simple to do but I am new to Python.

I am creating a code to ask the user how many gifts they want then to input the price. e.g. how many gifts do you want? `Giftswant = int(input())` then repeat `price = int(input())` until it has been repeated the same amount of times as `Giftswant`. The bit I am stuck at is in adding the prices together as there could be 1 to 100 inputs, I then need to print it.

```
 X = [] 
 Y = [x + x + x +.....]
 print Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `sum()` should do the job:

```
>>> x = [9.99,19.99,25.00]
>>> y = sum(x)
>>> print y
54.98
```